# Galois extension of a semilocal ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I wanna know if a finite Galois extension of a semi-local commutative ring is also semilocal.

Comment: Assuming that finite Galois extensions are finite ring extensions, if the semilocal ring $A$ can be viewed as a finite extension of a field $k$, then the answer is yes, since finiteness of $B/A$ and $A/k$ implies finiteness of $B/k,$ which guarantees $B$ is semilocal.